# Share text + links using intent

Tags: android, intentfilter, android-intent

I'm developing an app.
I want to share text and links in facebook, twitter etc using intents. I'm not sure how to send them both.

```
Intent s = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        s.setType("text/plain");
        s.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "SAmple");
        s.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(s, "Quote"));
```

If I add `<a href=#>SAmple</a>`, then it is not parsed as a link.

Can u guide me please!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the type specified in

```
s.setType("text/plain");
```

You can only send plain text. and if you want to support of HTML format you will modify the type as:

```
s.setType("text/html");
```

but this can limit your choices in Intent Chooser dialog (i.e may be only Gmail or none).

This is because it depends on which type of `Intent` installed application can handle. As far as I know facebook, twitter etc doesn't handle such type of `Intent`.

So the solution is: you can concatenate the Link at the end of Text message using `s.setType("text/plain");` to have more Intent receivers.